# Update a model's ID but save to old ID URL in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I have a model with an ID of, for example, an ID of 3. So it's URL is '/items/3' on the server. What I need to do, is the save() the Model with a new ID but send the request to the URL '/items/3', but with ID in the request body of, for example, 4.

How can one achieve this?

At the moment, if I set a new ID on the Model, it tries to send a PUT request to the new ID's URL. How can I specify to make the request to the old ID, but keep the new ID set on the Model. On success() of the PUT, I will navigate the user to the new URL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're searching for is the behavior or Model#save with the **wait flag** set to true: "*Pass {wait: true} if you'd like to wait for the server before setting the new attributes on the model.*".
It would send to the server the attributes updated, but will set them on the model only when the server answers.

Comment: Looking forward to your test, as the doc isn't that complete about this flag's behavior, but the code seems to point in that direction.